# JavaScript Font Metrics

Tags: javascript, fonts

Given (1) a font-family and (2) a unicode character code.

Is it possible to, within JavaScript, produce an image that looks like:

http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/tutorial/metrics.png

Basically, I want to:

- display the character itself (enlarged)
- get the various font metrics
- draw a bunch of light grey lines

Now, drawing the light grey lines is simple -- I just use SVG. However, how do I extract the font-metrics of the character?

Comment: For the baseline-height, you might have a look at [How can I get the height of the baseline of a certain font?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10247132/1048572)

Comment: http://pomax.nihongoresources.com/pages/Font.js/ might help.  Not sure if it contains all the metrics you need.

Answer (score 6):

Based on the [library](http://pomax.nihongoresources.com/pages/Font.js) mentioned above I made this codepen

http://codepen.io/sebilasse/pen/gPBQqm?editors=1010

[edit: capHeight is now based on the letter `H` as suggested by @sebdesign below]

HTML

```
<h4>
  Change font name
  <input value="Maven Pro"></input>
  <small>[local or google]</small> 
  and font size 
  <input value="40px" size=8></input>
  and 
  <button onclick="getMetrics()">
    <strong>get metrics</strong>
  </button>
</h4>
<div id="illustrationContainer"></div>
<pre id="log"></pre>
<canvas id="cvs" width="220" height="200"></canvas>
```

JS

```
    (getMetrics());

function getMetrics() {
  var testtext = "Sixty Handgloves ABC";
  // if there is no getComputedStyle, this library won't work.
  if(!document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {
    throw("ERROR: 'document.defaultView.getComputedStyle' not found. This library only works in browsers that can report computed CSS values.");
  }

  // store the old text metrics function on the Canvas2D prototype
  CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.measureTextWidth = CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.measureText;

  /**
   *  shortcut function for getting computed CSS values
   */
  var getCSSValue = function(element, property) {
    return document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element,null).getPropertyValue(property);
  };

  // debug function
  var show = function(canvas, ctx, xstart, w, h, metrics)
  {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)';

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(xstart,0);
    ctx.lineTo(xstart,h);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke(); 

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(xstart+metrics.bounds.maxx,0);
    ctx.lineTo(xstart+metrics.bounds.maxx,h);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke(); 

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0,h/2-metrics.ascent);
    ctx.lineTo(w,h/2-metrics.ascent);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke(); 

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0,h/2+metrics.descent);
    ctx.lineTo(w,h/2+metrics.descent);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  /**
   * The new text metrics function
   */
  CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.measureText = function(textstring) {
    var metrics = this.measureTextWidth(textstring),
        fontFamily = getCSSValue(this.canvas,"font-family"),
        fontSize = getCSSValue(this.canvas,"font-size").replace("px",""),
        isSpace = !(/\S/.test(textstring));
        metrics.fontsize = fontSize;

    // for text lead values, we meaure a multiline text container.
    var leadDiv = document.createElement("div");
    leadDiv.style.position = "absolute";
    leadDiv.style.opacity = 0;
    leadDiv.style.font = fontSize + "px " + fontFamily;
    leadDiv.innerHTML = textstring + "<br/>" + textstring;
    document.body.appendChild(leadDiv);

    // make some initial guess at the text leading (using the standard TeX ratio)
    metrics.leading = 1.2 * fontSize;

    // then we try to get the real value from the browser
    var leadDivHeight = getCSSValue(leadDiv,"height");
    leadDivHeight = leadDivHeight.replace("px","");
    if (leadDivHeight >= fontSize * 2) { metrics.leading = (leadDivHeight/2) | 0; }
    document.body.removeChild(leadDiv);

    // if we're not dealing with white space, we can compute metrics
    if (!isSpace) {
        // Have characters, so measure the text
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        var padding = 100;
        canvas.width = metrics.width + padding;
        canvas.height = 3*fontSize;
        canvas.style.opacity = 1;
        canvas.style.fontFamily = fontFamily;
        canvas.style.fontSize = fontSize;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.font = fontSize + "px " + fontFamily;

        var w = canvas.width,
            h = canvas.height,
            baseline = h/2;

        // Set all canvas pixeldata values to 255, with all the content
        // data being 0. This lets us scan for data[i] != 255.
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillRect(-1, -1, w+2, h+2);
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.fillText(textstring, padding/2, baseline);
        var pixelData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h).data;

        // canvas pixel data is w*4 by h*4, because R, G, B and A are separate,
        // consecutive values in the array, rather than stored as 32 bit ints.
        var i = 0,
            w4 = w * 4,
            len = pixelData.length;

        // Finding the ascent uses a normal, forward scanline
        while (++i < len && pixelData[i] === 255) {}
        var ascent = (i/w4)|0;

        // Finding the descent uses a reverse scanline
        i = len - 1;
        while (--i > 0 && pixelData[i] === 255) {}
        var descent = (i/w4)|0;

        // find the min-x coordinate
        for(i = 0; i<len && pixelData[i] === 255; ) {
          i += w4;
          if(i>=len) { i = (i-len) + 4; }}
        var minx = ((i%w4)/4) | 0;

        // find the max-x coordinate
        var step = 1;
        for(i = len-3; i>=0 && pixelData[i] === 255; ) {
          i -= w4;
          if(i<0) { i = (len - 3) - (step++)*4; }}
        var maxx = ((i%w4)/4) + 1 | 0;

        // set font metrics
        metrics.ascent = (baseline - ascent);
        metrics.descent = (descent - baseline);
        metrics.bounds = { minx: minx - (padding/2),
                           maxx: maxx - (padding/2),
                           miny: 0,
                           maxy: descent-ascent };
        metrics.height = 1+(descent - ascent);
    }

    // if we ARE dealing with whitespace, most values will just be zero.
    else {
        // Only whitespace, so we can't measure the text
        metrics.ascent = 0;
        metrics.descent = 0;
        metrics.bounds = { minx: 0,
                           maxx: metrics.width, // Best guess
                           miny: 0,
                           maxy: 0 };
        metrics.height = 0;
    }
    return metrics;
  };
  //callback();


  var fontName = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
  var fontSize = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[1].value;
  var WebFontConfig = {
    google: { 
      families: [ [encodeURIComponent(fontName),'::latin'].join('') ] 
    }
  };
  var wf = document.createElement('script');
  wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
    '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
  wf.type = 'text/javascript';
  wf.async = 'true';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
  document.body.style.fontFamily = ['"'+fontName+'"', "Arial sans"].join(' ')
  var canvas = document.getElementById('cvs'),
      context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  var w=220, h=200;

  canvas.style.font = [fontSize, fontName].join(' ');
  context.font = [fontSize, fontName].join(' ');
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  // draw bounding box and text
  var xHeight = context.measureText("x").height;
  var capHeight = context.measureText("H").height;
  var metrics = context.measureText("Sxy");
  var xStart = (w - metrics.width)/2;
  context.fontFamily = fontName;
  context.fillStyle = "#FFAF00";
  context.fillRect(xStart, h/2-metrics.ascent, metrics.bounds.maxx-metrics.bounds.minx, 1+metrics.bounds.maxy-metrics.bounds.miny);
  context.fillStyle = "#333333";
  context.fillText(testtext, xStart, h/2);
  metrics.fontsize = parseInt(metrics.fontsize);
  metrics.offset = Math.ceil((metrics.leading - metrics.height) / 2);
  metrics.width = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(metrics.width));
  metrics.capHeight = capHeight;
  metrics.xHeight = xHeight - 1;
  metrics.ascender = metrics.capHeight - metrics.xHeight;
  metrics.descender = metrics.descent;

  var myMetrics = {
    px: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(metrics)),
    relative: {
      fontsize: 1,
      offset: (metrics.offset / metrics.fontsize),
      height: (metrics.height / metrics.fontsize),
      capHeight: (metrics.capHeight / metrics.fontsize),
      ascender: (metrics.ascender / metrics.fontsize),
      xHeight: (metrics.xHeight / metrics.fontsize),
      descender: (metrics.descender / metrics.fontsize)
    },
    descriptions: {
      ascent: 'distance above baseline',
      descent: 'distance below baseline',
      height: 'ascent + 1 for the baseline + descent',
      leading: 'distance between consecutive baselines',
      bounds: { 
        minx: 'can be negative',
        miny: 'can also be negative',
        maxx: 'not necessarily the same as metrics.width',
        maxy: 'not necessarily the same as metrics.height'
      },
      capHeight: 'height of the letter H',
      ascender: 'distance above the letter x',
      xHeight: 'height of the letter x (1ex)',
      descender: 'distance below the letter x'
    }
  }

  Array.prototype.slice.call(
    document.getElementsByTagName('canvas'), 0
  ).forEach(function(c, i){
    if (i > 0) document.body.removeChild(c);
  });

  document.getElementById('illustrationContainer').innerHTML = [
'<div style="margin:0; padding:0; position: relative; font-size:',fontSize,'; line-height: 1em; outline:1px solid black;">',
  testtext,
  '<div class="__ascender" style="position: absolute; width:100%; top:',myMetrics.relative.offset,'em; height:',myMetrics.relative.ascender,'em; background:rgba(220,0,5,.5);"></div>',
    '<div class="__xHeight" style="position: absolute; width:100%; top:',myMetrics.relative.offset + myMetrics.relative.ascender,'em; height:',myMetrics.relative.xHeight,'em; background:rgba(149,204,13,.5);"></div>',
    '<div class="__xHeight" style="position: absolute; width:100%; top:',myMetrics.relative.offset + myMetrics.relative.ascender + myMetrics.relative.xHeight,'em; height:',myMetrics.relative.descender,'em; background:rgba(13,126,204,.5);"></div>',
  '</div>'
  ].join('');
  myMetrics.illustrationMarkup = document.getElementById('illustrationContainer').innerHTML;
  var logstring = ["/* metrics for", fontName, 
                   "*/\nvar metrics =", 
                   JSON.stringify(myMetrics, null, '  ')].join(' ');
  document.getElementById('log').textContent = logstring;
}
```

Comment: This is great! The only suggestion I would make is to calculate the capHeight from the height of the letter H. The letter S, usually curvy, has optical adjustments to make it appear the same height as other letters, but it's actually taller than flat letters. Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cap_height and http://www.typographydeconstructed.com/cap-height/.

Comment: Useful code! I made sebdesign's suggested change and it did make a difference.

Comment: I tested the xHeight calculation and measured it manually on two fonts, the calculation is wrong. In the line "metrics.xHeight = xHeight - 1;", the "- 1" should not be there. "metrics.xHeight = xHeight;" is correct.