# How can I detect where the text baseline is positioned

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, vertical-alignment

If I have a set of HTML that looks like this:

```html
<div>
    This is some text, followed by an image
    <img src="some image with height greater than the text" />
</div>
```

And the image is set to be vertically-aligned in the middle:

```css
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Then the text will end up being positioned lower in the div so it lines up with the middle of the image. See an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/RGWny/

**Is there any way to use javascript (or jquery, or any jquery plugin) to detect the actual position of the text?**

I'm looking for a way to get either the size of the gap above the text (in px/pt/em/etc), or the distance down from the top of the `<div>` to the text's baseline.

I'd like to avoid actually calculating where the position *should be* by looking at the image size, etc. The text is dynamic and may or may not contain multiple images, which may or may not be on the first line of text. I need to position another element relative to the vertical position of the first line of the text.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56294105/4779501

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap each text node inside your `div` into `span` either server-side or even client-side, like in code below. Then it is quite simple to measure 'the gap above the text' - it is just the vertical position of text-`span` relative to its parent `div`.

```
<div id='x'>
    This is some text, followed by an image
    <img style="vertical-align:middle" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/R/S/Z/4/t/f/crossed-hammers-bw-100x100-md.png" />
</div>
<script>
function wrapTextNodes(jqelem) {
    jqelem.contents()
        .filter( function() { return this.nodeType===3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue); } )
        .wrap("<span class='was-text'></span>");
}
wrapTextNodes( $('#x') );

$('#x span.was-text').each( function() {
    alert( $(this).position().top );
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice clean solution. I had considered automatically wrapping the text in a span, but I couldn't think of an elegant way to do it - I like the combination of `contents()` and `filter()` here.

Comment: A couple updates though - I'd use `$.trim` instead of the built-in `String.trim` which isn't universally supported: `$.trim(this.nodeValue).length`. Also, the `.end()` does nothing here and can be removed entirely.

Comment: Agreed about `$.trim` and `.end()`... The next step to minimalism -  `.length` property is not needed too, becasue empty string converts to boolean false itself. Updated code sample above.

Comment: Note that IE does not have the `Node.TEXT_NODE` constant available. You'll need to use `3` instead, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423599/node-text-node-and-ie7