# How to absolutely position the baseline of text in HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm puzzled by the following problem. I wish to (absolutely) position the baseline of some piece of HTML text at a certain y-coordinate, while the text should be starting at a certain x-coordinate. The following diagram clearly demonstrates the issue.

[image: a diagram]

So I basically want to control where the point (x,y), henceforth called the "basepoint", in the diagram is located on the screen, relative to the top-left corner of the BODY of the document or some DIV. Important: I don't know beforehand what the font-family or font-size of the text is. This is important, because I don't want to change all the positions in my CSS whenever I change fonts.

In the following code, I try to position the basepoint at (200,100), but instead it positions the top-left of the DIV at that point.

```
<html>
    <style>
        BODY
        {
            position: absolute;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        #text
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 100px;
            left: 200px;

            font-family: helvetica, arial; /* may vary */
            font-size: 80px;               /* may vary */
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div id="text">css=powerful</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So how should I modify this code? Should I use the vertical-align property of the enclosing DIV? (I tried, but couldn't get the desired result).

Thanks for any useful replies.

Comment: Zach is right, since it's absolute position you can move it.

Comment: Is this what you want ? http://jsfiddle.net/4u4qw/

Comment: @Ani No, he means align the text baseline starting at the point given

Comment: Dang, I was too slow. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MMVj3/)

Answer (score 3):

Hacky solution based on [this blog post](https://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2014/08/13/one-weird-trick-to-baseline-align-text/).

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="text">css=powerful</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#text {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 0px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
#text:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 120px;
}
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dg0wdLb5/). The basepoint is aligned to (100, 120).

Answer (score 2):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MMVj3/1/) Goofy (and crazy ugly/hacky), but it works.

```
<body>
    <div id="spacer"></div>
    <div id="text">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/10X100" id="baseline">css=powerful</div>
</body>
```

...

```
    body {
        margin: 0px;
    }

    #spacer {
        float: left;
        width: 190px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
    }
    #baseline {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    #text {
        float: left;
        background-color: yellow;
        font-family: helvetica, arial; /* may vary */
        font-size: 60px;               /* may vary */
    }
```

*Edit*
I guess, really, it's all about the image. So you could just simplify and use a transparent spacer gif. Still stupid hacky, I know.
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MMVj3/2/)

Comment: Spacer images! Welcome to 2001. :)

Comment: Well it works, but I was looking for a more elegant solution. HTML/CSS is the world's most-used formatting language, so there must be an elegant way do deal with this rather simple problem (right?)

Comment: @peterp Yep, I agree. But it looks like a hacky mess like I posted or a javascript solution may be the only way. After all, if it was an easy problem, you'd have two dozen answers by now. :)

Comment: @peterp It really comes down to the image letting you work with the baseline. So you could just use a transparent gif [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MMVj3/2/)
I'm obsessing now :) I want to see what the CSS experts come up with. :P

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

HTML :

```
<div id="text-holder">
 <div id="text-holder-position"></div>
 <div id="text">css=powerful</div>
</div>
<div id="heightJudger"></div>
```

CSS :

```
    BODY
{
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px;
}
#text
{
    position: relative;
    margin-top:-0.938em;
    left:0px;
    font-family: helvetica, arial;
    font-size: 80px;

    /*You can remove this*/
    background: yellow;
    opacity: 0.5;

}
#text-holder
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    left: 200px;
}

#text-holder-position {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: green;
}

#heightJudger {
    position:absolute;
    height:200px; width:200px;
    background:red;
    top:0; left:0;
}
```

if you want to change the position, change the "height" and the "left" parameters of the     `#text-holder`
This way you will be able to control your basepoint position.
I put the height judger and some color so you can see if it's what you exepct.

**EDIT :** Changed the #text margin unit to em.
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j7NTK/9/)

Comment: This aligns the **bottom** of the DIV to y=100, whereas the intention was to align the **baseline** to y=100.

Comment: And then this aligns the baseline to the bottom of the div, to y=100

Comment: @user3077606 Have a look at Zach's jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/atKqX/ (forked) which clearly shows that the bottom of the div is aligned to y=100, and NOT the baseline.

Comment: This picture shows what is still the problem with this approach: ![a problem](http://i.imgur.com/AerMnOJ.png)

Comment: I have edited the code, i hope you was expecting this. I just changed the position.

Comment: Now it aligns correctly indeed! But... when I change the font-size to 10px, it doesn't anymore...

Comment: Maybe using script is necessary? [Check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247132/how-can-i-get-the-height-of-the-baseline-of-a-certain-font)

Comment: I don't know how to do better only using HTML and CSS sorry

Comment: It has been a long time, but I figured out how to fix the problem with low font sizes, so I wanted to update this in case someone else wonder how to do it. I edited the answer with the new JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

By default inline-block/inline and text in block are baseline vertical-aligned. Create an pseudo element inside the block you want to move in Y and defining the height of this spacer.

```css
/**
Create a vertical spacer. It will be aligned with the parent's content baseline:
**/
.text::before{
  content: "";
  /*the Y value:*/
  height: 100px;
  width: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

/**
The rest (only for this demo)
**/
body{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin: 0;
}
body::before{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  margin: -1px 0;
  background-color: #00D500;
  z-index: 1;
}
body::after{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 200px;
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  margin: -4px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #FF0077;
  z-index: 1;
}

.text {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  /*the X value:*/
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<p class="text">css=powerful</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a single line of text, using `margin-top: -1em` on the text did the trick for me.

This just moves the element up by one font-size, therefore letting you position it by the baseline.