# CSS: Absolutely position text by baseline?

Tags: html, css

I have the coordinates for text that needs to be absolutely positioned on the page, but the coordinates I have are for the baseline of the text, not the top left corner of the text (which could be anything depending the characters.)

Currently the text will be positioned by the top-left corner, which makes it impossible to position my text accurately.

How can I set the absolute position of the baseline of the text? That is, the I want to specify the position of the baseline of the text, not the top of the text.

Please see: https://jsfiddle.net/8hnjoo68/

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; font-size: 42px;">This text should be off the page because it's baseline is set at 0.</div>
<div style="position:absolute; top:42px; left:0px; font-size: 42px;">Second line of text should be where the first one is, more or less.</div>
```

Comment: "How can I set the absolute position of the baseline of the text"--not clear about question what u wan ask

Comment: The baseline is the bottom of the line of text, excluding hanging characters (e.g. jgy, etc.) It is how text is normally positioned, by baseline.

Comment: Related (or perhaps even a duplicate?): [How to absolutely position the baseline of text in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20443220/1468366)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to wrap both `divs` in a `div` with relative positioning. That way when you set the `bottom: 0` it will actually move relative to that `div` giving you the illusion of disappearing.

Example [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYKWGp)

Note that you will probably see a little of the hanging letters. To adjust this you just need to add more to the `bottom: 20px;`

```
<div style="position:relative;">
    <div style="position:absolute; bottom: 0; left:0px; font-size: 42px;">This text should be off the page because it's baseline is set at 0.</div>
    <div style="position:absolute; left:0px; font-size: 42px;">Second line of text should be where the first one is, more or less.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately this approach does not work when text is wrapped

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option. I use my baselining method to get consistent leading, so you don't need to worry about font metrics. Then I move all the boxes so they are off the screen with translate. Use `top` to place the bottom baseline of the box where you'd like it to go.

```css
/* 1. Include a baselined font */
@font-face {
  font-family: "Baseline Em";
  src: url("https://rawgit.com/shalanah/baseline/98e925b/BaselineEm/baselineem-webfont.woff2") format("woff2"), url("https://rawgit.com/shalanah/baseline/98e925b/BaselineEm/baselineem-webfont.woff") format("woff"), url("https://rawgit.com/shalanah/baseline/98e925b/BaselineEm/baselineem-webfont.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

/* Simple reset */
body, html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

/* 2. Setting block elements up - Leading */
div {
  font-family: "Baseline Em", sans-serif; /* Baselined font only needed at block level */
  line-height: 1em;
  font-size: 42px; /* equivalent to leading */
}

/* 3. Setting up font and font-size */)
span {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 30px; /* whatever size you want, but will affect how many lines */
}

/* 4. Positioning */
div:nth-of-type(1) {
 outline: 3px dotted blue;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 transform: translateY(-100%);
}

/* Positioning */
div:nth-of-type(2) {
 outline: 3px dotted red;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 42px;
 transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div><span>1st line of text</span></div>
<div><span>2nd line of text</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bhavuksuthar/Lsrymm04/) for you

I hope thats what you are asking for. You can alter the `css` accordingly to keep the top line fixed or scroll the page when browser resize.

Key is `bottom` and `top` properties.

Comment: Hi Mike, that's not what I mean.

Comment: @Alasdair ok so can you include any image or any live sample link of same thing you want to achieve. That will help more to achieve that