# Get the baseline height of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fonts, baseline

How can I find the height of the baseline of an element depending on its font?

I need something like:
    var foo = $('#foo');
    console.log(getBaseline(foo));

```
function getBaseline(foo){
   //do something
   return baseline;
}
```

@Edit
Question marked as solution gives me something like "0.89". Another person asks the same in the comments

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the height of the baseline of a certain font?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247132/how-can-i-get-the-height-of-the-baseline-of-a-certain-font)

Comment: i tried. didn't work